# Adapting .NET 4.5 async to F#

Tags: f#, .net-4.5

The .NET 4.5 framework libraries integrate C#-style Task-based async fairly extensively. In many cases, they also continue to expose APM-style Begin/End method pairs. F# can easily adapt either method to F#-style asynchronous computations.

My question is, given an IO-bound operation that's implemented in the framework as both Begin/End and Task-based async, is there a performance or memory advantage to choosing one over the other when adapting to F# async?

For example, in .NET 4.5, `System.IO.Stream` has both [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx). That means I can do this...

```
type System.IO.Stream with
    member x.AsyncRead(buffer, offset, count) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd(buffer, offset, count, x.BeginRead, x.EndRead)
```

Or I can do this...

```
type System.IO.Stream with
    member x.AsyncRead(buffer, offset, count) =
        x.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? The main difference that I can think of is that the read operation will have already started when the second extension method returns, but not so with the first extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`AsyncRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340397.aspx) extension method ([implemented in terms of `FromBeginEnd`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1737-1741)) is already defined in FSharp.Core. [`AwaitTask`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1717-1728) is just a thin wrapper over [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx). So it boils down to a comparison of `Task` and `async`--which is more efficient, or *right* for the job. Since you're working with `async`s, the only relevant difference would be performance. I'm not an expert on this, but I think `async` and `Task` address the same issue, with `Task` having an edge for CPU-bound operations.

#### EDIT

I didn't read your question carefully enough. I don't know the definitive answer, but given that `Task` and `async` are roughly equivalent, I don't see any reason to wrap a `Task` with an `async` unless it's your only option. `Begin/End` methods are a lower-level, more lightweight abstraction, and therefore seem like better building blocks for `async`s.

An ancillary thought: the fact that `AsyncRead` wasn't changed to use `Task` *could* be instructive.

Comment: I'm aware that AsyncRead already exists, that was just an example. My question is, given an IO-bound operation that's implemented in the framework as both Begin/End and Task-based async, is there a performance or memory advantage to choosing one over the other when adapting to F# async?

Comment: Ah, sorry...I didn't read your question carefully enough. I don't know the answer, but I would go with `FromBeginEnd` because it adds the least overhead. Building an `async` on top of `Task` seems superfluous for anything other than interop.

Comment: Well, hopefully there's not much overhead, because when C# 5 goes live, I have a feeling we're going to be doing a lot of building an `async` on top of `Task`...  Given that Task-based async is simply the way async is done in C# 5, I was hoping someone would know how well it's been optimized in .NET 4.5 compared to what we're accustomed to in F#.

Comment: The event-based asynchronous pattern has been around much longer than `Task`, so I suspect there will almost always be (at least in the BCL) a `Begin/End` alternative available. Everything else fits in the interop category, and interop is rarely optimally efficient.

Comment: [StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) is one example of a place in the BCL that uses Task-based async with no Begin/End alternative available. I doubt they would drop any existing Begin/End pairs, but I expect to see a proliferation of Task-only async in new API's.

Comment: Then perhaps that's a good indication that there is no substantial performance difference, or if there is it's outweighed by the benefits.